# C# - Ping server with ICMP disabled

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, icmp

I am trying to ping a series of servers frequently using the [PingReply](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.pingreply.aspx) class.  Most of the time this is fine, but other times I get failed pings.  I'm guessing this has something to do with ICMP being disabled on the remote server(s).  Is there any way to get a ping to from a server even if ICMP is disabled?

Comment: If ICMP ECHO is disabled on the responding server, how could the Ping command work?

Comment: I assumed they used the same ICMP reply.  you could wire sharke the command line ping and see whats going on.

Comment: I just tested it a few more times and I can't replicate the issue with the command line.  Maybe that instance that I tested wasn't an ICMP issue. But the rest must be, because neither the PingReply class nor the ping command return anything.  I updated the question.

Comment: What does "accurate ping" mean in relation to a server that doesn't respond to pings?

Comment: I didn't mean anything explicitly. I just meant something that would yield results as "accurately" as the PingReply would.

Comment: @Nate: What information are you trying to determine with your ping? Available options include: "Is the server up?", "What's the TTL?", "What's the maximum packet size?", and "What's the round trip time?".

Comment: I'm just trying to determine if the server (accessed directly by it's IP) is online and get the round trip time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the remote server won't respond to an ICMP ECHO request, it won't work with the Ping command. Odds are there is some difference between the packet you're sending and the one Ping is sending. You can use something like Network Monitor or [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html) to see the packets and compare them.

Odds are you're sending a packet with a lower TTL (or maybe too big of a buffer). I would try increasing `PingOptions.Ttl` first.

Comment: @Nate: Please update your question to tell us what "accurate ping" means.

Answer (score 0):

The ping command also uses ICMP. If you know of a port that will reliably be open on that machine, you can always establish a telnet connection.